# Repeating numpy array elements according to another index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following placeholder array:

```
placeholder = np.zeros(10)
```

`A` contains the values that I want to go in to the placeholder

```
A = np.array([25, 40, 65,50])
```

`idx` has the indices of the placeholder ( note that this has the same shape as `A`)

```
idx = np.array([0, 5, 6, 8])
```

**Question:**

I want `placeholder` to be populated with the elements of `A`. The amount to which an element in `A` to be repeated is defined by the length of the intervals of the `idx` array.

For example, 25 is repeated 5 times because the corresponding index range is [0, 5). 65 is repeated twice because the corresponding index range is [6,8)

Expected output:

```
np.array([25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 65, 65, 50, 50])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and easy, using `np.diff` + `np.repeat`:

```
repeats = np.diff(np.append(idx, len(placeholder)))

A.repeat(repeats)
array([25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 65, 65, 50, 50])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `placeholder` array:

```
import numpy as np

placeholder = np.zeros(10)
A = np.array([25, 40, 65,50])
idx = np.array([0, 5, 6, 8])

placeholder[idx[0]] = A[0]
placeholder[idx[1:]] = np.diff(A)    
np.cumsum(placeholder, out=placeholder)
```

Comment: This solution is out of this world! Unfortunately, I had to accept the other one because of it's readability.